# SQL - Inquiry about calling subqueries names

Tags: sql, teradata

Let's say I have this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_0.*, TABLE_A.*
FROM (
    SELECT TABLE_0.*,
    CAST... -- and more variable creations/transformations
    FROM (
        SELECT TABLE_0.*,
        VARIABLE_1 + 2 AS VARIABLE_3,
        CAST... -- and more variable creations/transformations
        FROM (
            SELECT TABLE_0.*,
            VARIABLE_1 + 1 AS VARIABLE_2.. -- and more variable creations/transformations
            FROM TABLE_0 -- Let's call this table TABLE_0 v1
            ) TABLE_0 -- Let's call this table TABLE_0 v2
        WHERE YearMonth < 202001
        ) TABLE_0 -- Let's call this table TABLE_0 v3
    WHERE Product_Category IN (123,456,789)
    ) TABLE_0 -- Let's call this table TABLE_0 v4
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A
ON TABLE_0.YearMonth = TABLE_A.YearMonth AND TABLE_0.Client_ID = TABLE_A.Client_ID
```

- When I'm doing the `LEFT JOIN` and calling `YearMonth` and `Client_ID` from `TABLE_0`, from which `TABLE_0` (v1 to v4) will pick up those variables in order to do the `LEFT JOIN`?
- Is there any concern I should have when JOINING tables with multiple subqueries with the same name (as the example above)?
- Does `TABLE_0` `v1`, `v2`, `v3` exist at the level of doing the JOIN? If they do, how SQL recognizes to which TABLE_0 will call when I'm using it?

Comment: The parser is aware of the scope of an object in your query.  In other words, if you re-use an alias like that, it knows what objects are available to that particular alias. You certainly can reuse aliases inside subqueries, derived tables, etc, but as you can see it gets confusing to read, or make sense of error messages.  I certainly wouldn't recommend something like you've got.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew! But.. if I change (by mistake) the name of the last table (for `TABLE_0` v4, let's say I put `TABLE_00`). Would use TABLE_0 v3 in this case? Or it would raise an error that it doesn't recognize the table when JOINING or calling the variables?

Comment: There is no `v1`, `v2`, or `v3` in your query, so I'm confused.

Comment: @Chris - if I understand your question correctly, you would get an error.  If the object doesn't exist in the current scope, the query will fail.

Comment: I reuse aliases (but `dt` instead of `TABLE_0`) a lot as I don't want to think about a descriptive name for each Derived Table.